# How can I automatically escape from an running program with timeout in a .sh file?

Tags: bash, sh

Could anyone tell me how to automatically escape to another line within a bash script after an appointed timeout(maybe 300 second) when a execution program(which start up by the same .sh file) is still running?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want the previous line to abort and proceed to the next line? You can use `timeout -s KILL 300 command` will send a `KILL` signal to `command` after `300` seconds. Assuming you are on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running on Linux, it comes with `coreutils`.

```
timeout -s KILL 300 command1
command2
```

`timeout` will send a `KILL` signal to `command1` if it is still running after `300` seconds has elapsed. The exit status will be `124` if timeout occurred, otherwise the exit status is the exit status of `command1`.

Answer (score -1):

You can run it in the background.

```
cmd1 &
sleep 300
cmd2
```

Comment: How does this enforce a time limit? Instead, this lets `cmd1` run as long as it wants, while `cmd2` must wait 300 seconds before running.

Comment: You can kill cmd1 after 300 seconds before/after running cmd2

Comment: Yes. You have to do it yourself. But not that hard. $! will have the process id.

Comment: It's not about how hard it is—this doesn't answer the question, which was "how to **automatically** escape to another line".

Comment: but if cmd1's execution time more than 300 sec, and I want to stop cmd1 when the time is up. is that ok for this? anyway, i will try it, thanks!

Comment: This answer is vague, at best. `cmd2` could be `kill $cmd1_pid`, but that should be explicit.